# Laravel Save Multiple Data to 1 column

Tags: laravel

So I have 2 variable for storing the selected time of the user ('time_to' and 'time_from) with these sample data('7:30','8:00')
How can I save these two into 1 column('c_time') so it would look like this('7:30-8:00')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if i understand you correctly, you can create a column of `string (varchar)` type. and then create the data for your column like this :

```
$time_to = '7:30';
$time_from= '8:00';
$colValueToBeStored = "(".$time_to."-".$time_from.")";
```

then just put `$colValueToBeStored` inside your column.

and to reverse it:

```
$colValueToBeStored  = "(7:30-8:00)";
$res = explode("-",str_replace([")","("],"",$colValueToBeStored));
$time_to = $res[0];
$time_from = $res[1];
```

Comment: Are you still around?

Comment: yes, how can i help?@itsmejoe

Comment: How about doing the inverse on edit() ? I'd want the $colValueToBeStored to be exploded again to $time_to and $time_from. TIA

Comment: i added the reverse part to answer. @itsmejoe

Comment: Woah Big thanks,

Answer (score 1):

define your `c_time` column type as [JSON](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#column-method-json), that way you can store multiple values, as it will be easier to retrieve as well. Like,

```
...
$cTime['time_to'] = "7:30";
$cTime['time_from'] = "8:00";
$cTimeJson = json_encode($cTime);
// save to db
...
```